# Java String split regexp returns empty strings with multiple delimiters

Tags: java, regex, string

I have a problem that I can't seem to find an answer here for, so I'm asking it.

The thing is that I have a string and I have delimiters. I want to create an array of strings from the things which are between those delimiters (might be words, numbers, etc). However, if I have two delimiters next to one another, the split method will return an empty string for one of the instances.

I tested this against even more delimiters that are in succession. I found out that if I have n delimiters, I will have n-1 empty strings in the result array. In other words, if I have both "," and " " as delimiters, and the sentence "**This is a very nice day, isn't it**", then the array with results would be like:

```
{... , "day", "", "isn't" ...}
```

I want to get those extra empty strings out and I can't figure out how to do that. A sample regex for the delimiters that I have is:

```
"[\\s,.-\\'\\[\\]\\(\\)]"
```

Also can you explain why there are extra empty strings in the result array?

P.S. I read some of the similar posts which included information about the second parameter of the regex. I tried both negative, zero, and positive numbers, and I didn't get the result that I'm looking for. (one of the questions had an answer saying that -1 as a parameter might solve the problem, but it didn't.

Comment: So what's your code then?

Comment: this isn't code bound, I think that the problem is with the parameters, or the way that String uses Pattern and Matcher to create the array of results

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this regex for splitting:

```
[\\s,.'\\[\\]()-]+
```

- Keep unescaped hyphen at first or last position in character class otherwise it is treated as range like `A-Z` or `0-9`
- You must use quantifier `+` for matching 1 more delimiters

Comment: The reason why hyphen is first/last?

Comment: Added more details about that also

Comment: Yes, but since it's a delimiter for a range, wouldn't it be better if you espcaped the hyphen or something?

Comment: Yes you can use: `[\\s,.\\-'\\[\\]()]+` also but `[\\s,.'\\[\\]()-]+` is much cleaner

Answer (score 1):

Your regular expression describes just one single character. If you want it to match multiple separators at once, use a quantifier:

```
String s = "This is a very nice day, isn't it";
String[] tokens = s.split("[\\s,.\\-\\[\\]()']+");
```

(Note the '`+`' at the end of the expression)

Comment: I had no idea that I could use the + as in regular regexp's, thanks

Answer (score 1):

I think your problem is just the regex itself. You should use a greedy quantifier:

```
"[\\s,.-\\'\\[\\]\\(\\)]+"
```

See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#sum

> X+    ... X, one or more times

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get rid of empty strings, you can use the Guava project [Splitter](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/) class.

## `on` method:

> Returns a splitter that uses the given fixed string as a separator.

**Example (ignoring empty strings):**

```
System.out.println(
                Splitter.on(',')
                   .trimResults()
                   .omitEmptyStrings()
                   .split("foo,bar,,   qux")
                );
```

**Output:**

```
[foo, bar, qux]
```

## `onPattern` method:

> Returns a `splitter` that considers any subsequence matching a given
>   pattern (regular expression) to be a separator.

**Example (ignoring empty strings):**

```
System.out.println(
                Splitter
                .onPattern("([,.|])")
                .trimResults()
                .omitEmptyStrings()
                .split("foo|bar,,  qux.hi")
                );
```

**Output:**

```
[foo, bar, qux, hi]
```

For more details, consult Splitter [documentation](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/base/Splitter.html).

Comment: @Mackiavelli Have you tried to use Splitter class? Here is the [documentation](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/base/Splitter.html).